# Data format for phylosignal, ape and phylobase packages

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I am trying to perform a test similar to the phylosignal (navic) and phylobase (geospiza) package dataset. However, I cannot seem to get the data frame correct, I have tried to print the data on R and save it on an excel sheet but I run into the same errors when I run the codes. Here is a link to my dataset (https://www.dropbox.com/s/36akifw32ou81q5/larkbodyweight.xlsx?dl=0). When I try to run the codes I get the following errors:

Error in UseMethod("dotplot") :
no applicable method for 'dotplot' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

Error in as(from, "phylo4") :
no method or default for coercing “tbl_df” to “phylo4”

```
    dotplot(larkbodyweight, trait = names(tdata(larkbodyweight)))
```

```
    barplot.phylo4d(larkbodyweight)
```

Comment: Could you edit your post with the code you tried ? It is impossible to help you as we don't know which code produced this error

Comment: Hi Bastien, thank you for your engagement. I do think the main issue is the data frame of my data.

Comment: This is normal you have this error as `dotplot` and `barplot.phylo4d` from phylosignal package require "a `phylo4d` object" as input and not a dataframe. I think you will need to create a `phylo4d` object from a phylogenetic tree corresponding to the species in your dataset

Comment: I am still getiing the ('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame') error. The format of my data is not readable somehow. When I print my data in R and the navic (dataset in the phylosignal package) they look different.

Comment: You misunderstood me, your dataset is not readable for the `dotplot` and `barplot.phylo4d` function, you have to first create a `phylo4d` object with `phylo4d()` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/phylobase/versions/0.8.10/topics/phylo4d-methods